# How to get last inserted row id using room android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

**I want to get the last row id in room android using kotlin**
**here is my Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "tb_customer")
data class Customer(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var customerId: Long = 0L,
        val firstName: String,
        val lastName: String,
        val emailAddress: String,
        val address: String,
        val profileImage: String?)
```

**my Dao**

```
@Dao
interface CustomerDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(customer: Customer): Long

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertPhones(customerPhones: ArrayList<CustomerPhones>)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(customer: Customer)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(customer: Customer)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tb_customer ORDER BY customerId ASC")
    fun getAllCustomers(): LiveData<List<Customer>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM tb_customer")
    suspend fun clear()
}
```

**Please help me to get last inserted id **

Comment: Can I use this `@Query("SELECT customerId FROM tb_customer ORDER BY customerId DESC LIMIT 1")
    fun getLastCustomer()`

Comment: "SELECT * FROM tb_customer ORDER BY customerId DESC LIMIT 1"
use this

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer you could try this code
**Dao**

```
@Query("SELECT customerId FROM tb_customer ORDER BY customerId DESC LIMIT 1")
    fun getLastCustomer(): LiveData<Long>
```

a**nd this is the repository **

```
fun getLastCustomer(): LiveData<Long> {
        return customerDao.getLastCustomer()
    }
```

**and this is the view model**

```
fun getLastCustomer(): LiveData<Long> {
        return repository.getLastCustomer()
    }
```

and finally from your context your have to  write

```
 customerViewModel.getLastCustomer().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{id->
            Log.d("TAG ", id.toString())
        })
```